# android permissions vs linux permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Are android permissions (the ones that you request in the manifest and are presented at the install time) the same thing with the linux permissions that the root user obtains on a rooted phone?

More exactly: if I have root on my phone and I have an app that whats to make a call but has not requested permission for this in the manifest, will the call succeed or will the app crash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Android permissions are implemented as Linux permissions (for example, External Storage or Network each confer membership in a Unix group that is allowed to do those operations), while others are implemented entirely within the Android layers.

"Root" has little to do with this, as it is all but unheard of for the main process of an Android app (which can access the various Android-level services) to run as root.  Instead, when people install root hacks on their devices, what they are doing is adding a shim which can let a *helper* program run as root - not the app itself.  If what the helper program wants to do is based on a Linux API, and restricted by a Linux permission, than this may work, to the extent that it is a traditional user/group based enforcement, and not also blocked by an SELinux one (to get around which, some of the hacks start the helper from a daemon that is itself initialized early upon boot before SELinux is fully activated).

But for things which have to be done through Android APIs, root can be nearly irrelevant, as normally the code doing the task won't be running as root.  It is possible that some of the command-line tools for interacting with Android APIs by firing up a distinct VM instance might have enhanced privileges there - but that is very different from trying to do the same things within your app's process.

People also sometimes leverage root access to drop their .apk on the system partition (if they can mount it writable) which allows some manifest permissions to be granted which would be ignored if found in the manifest of the same .apk when it is installed in the normal manner on the data partition.

Answer (score 2):

Having rooted phone does not impact Android permissions. In other words, if an app does "something" that requires certain permission(s), and the app does not declare them in AndroidManifest, the app will crash.

More in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The app would crash. Something interesting to know is that the permissions that you declare in the "androidmanifest" are actually implemented in the native android frameworks, which is mostly the java framework layer and a little bit on the cpp native implementations of such framework. You may corroborate this by looking into the Android OpenSource Project code. These permissions are actually a different layer of security policies implemented on Android, what's interesting about android is that ti inherits a lot of linux based permissions, one example is using the user, andrd user groups permissions to encapsulate running applications(each running app have a different group and user), and also, starting from android 5, SELinux is being enabled as well.

It is fair to say that all these mechanisms work together to tighten android's security as a whole.